# Alternative form of the geodesic equations

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, geodesics

In Hobson's General Relativity for physics, a geodesic is described as a curve satisfying $\frac{d\boldsymbol{t}}{du}=f(u)t$, where $u$ is a general parameter, $f(u)$ is some function of $u$ and $\boldsymbol{t}$ is the tangent vector to the geodesic curve $x^a(u)$. Now, the curve it's said to be affinely parametrised if $f(u)=0$, and so $\frac{d\boldsymbol{t}}{du}=0$.

At this point, it's assumed in the book that $\frac{d\boldsymbol{t}}{du}=0$ implies $\frac{D{t^a}}{Du}=0$, where $D$ stands for the intrinsic (or absolute) derivative, and I guess this is happening because in a general coordinate system, the proper derivative to take is not the usual one, but the intrinsic one. Anyway, the problem comes a couple sections later, when an alternative form of the geodesic equation is derived: $$\dot{t}^a=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_ag_{cd})t^ct^d$$

The procedure is clearly detailed, so I have no problem following it, but at the begining of it, it's stated:

> For a geodesic, we have $\frac{d\boldsymbol{t}}{du}=0$. This implies that, in some coordinate system, we may write this equation in terms of the intrinsic derivative of the covariant components of the tangent vector as $\frac{Dt_a}{Du}=0$.

From here, the equation follows easily, but I don't understand how this last statement holds, and that actually made me question why did $\frac{D{t^a}}{Du}=0$ follow from $\frac{d\boldsymbol{t}}{du}=0$ instead of $\frac{Dt_a}{Du}=0$, or is it that we can relate both the intrinisic derivatives of the covariant and contravariant components of the tangent vector in such a way that $\frac{Dt^a}{Du}=0$ implies $\frac{Dt_a}{Du}=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding out myself. After doing some research, I got to check that the covariant derivative of the metric tensor is null, so the operation of raising and lowering indexes with the metric tensor can be exchanged with a covariant derivative. This is: $$\nabla_cv^a=\nabla_c(g^{ab}v_b)=(\nabla_cg^{ab})v_b+g^{ab}\nabla_c(v_b)=g^{ab}\nabla_c(v_b)$$

From this reasoning, and writing the intrinsic derivative as $\frac{Dv^a}{Du}=(\nabla_cv^a)\frac{dx^c}{du}^*$, it's clear that $\frac{Dv^a}{Du}=0$ necessarily implies $\frac{Dv_a}{Du}=0$, since you can perform an index rising operation on it.

$^*$Note that, if $\boldsymbol{v}$ is only defined along the curve, it's covariant derivative wouldn't be formally defined and this wouldn't be 'true', though it holds for the sake of our argument.

Answer (score -1):

In Euclidean space, in an inertial frame,  objects without a resultant force acting on them are either at rest or move in straight lines. This is Newtons first law.

Since geodesics are the straight lines in non-Euclidean geometry then a similar statement should also be available for them. It turns out that this is the case:

We can always derive a path on a manifold and this gives us the velocity field which is a vector field along the path. Now, to derive the velocity field to give us the acceleration field we can't simply derive like we did the path, this requires a connection. For any pseudo-Riemannian manifold there is a canonical connection called the Levi-Civita connection. When we derive the velocity field with this connection we get the acceleration field.

Thus, geodesics, that is straight lines, on pseudo-Riemannian manifolds are paths which particles follow when they are unaccelerated. In particular, this includes Lorentzian manifolds and hence the manifolds on which GR is predicated upon.

(Notice that for general manifolds there are many different accelerations, one for every connection. It's only in the pseudo-Riemannian case, and hence the Lorentzian case, we get to pick a canonical one).

Comment: Small comment, it's not really correct to call geodesics 'straight lines in non-Euclidean geometry': straight lines in flat space are geodesics, but geodesics generally aren't straight lines. But you can say they're analogous to, or a generalisation of, straight lines for non-Euclidean spaces.

Comment: @Eletie: That's being a little pedantic to my mind ... the whole answer is drawing out an analogy between Newtonian Mechanics and Einsteinian mechanics. I think anyone who understands what I've written will understand what I mean; after all, you understood it, even though you're against interpreting it in this fashion.

Comment: I don't see the need to write things that are incorrect if they're not even conceptually simpler. The OP is dealing with GR and nowhere implies they need simplifications about geodesics. A key feature of curved space is that there *are* no straight lines.

Comment: @Eletie: He's asking for "An alternative derivation of the geodesic equations". I suggested a mechanical analogy. Geodesics are *conceptually* the straight lines in Non-Euclidean geometry. For example, in the synthetic approach to non-Euclidean geonetry, they say for spherical geometry, all *lines* intersect - that is all *great circles*. Great circles are curves, yet they call them lines ...

Comment: @Eletie: Generally when asked to draw a line, we draw *straight lines* not a squiggly curve.

Comment: Yes, geodesics are conceptually analogous to straight lines, we're in agreement! I have no problem with the word line being used synonymously with curve, but calling a great circle a 'straight line' would clearly be incorrect. There isn't a notion of a straight line on a sphere.

Comment: Your point about drawing a straight line vs a squiggly line is irrelevant, if somebody asks what curve locally minimises the distance between two points on a sphere and you say a straight line that's incorrect. Also the OP was asking about a specific set of equations, perhaps you misread the title (they weren't asking for an alternative derivation). The answer given doesn't seem to actually address the question.

Comment: @Eletie: As I've already pointed out, in the synthetic approach to non-Euclidean geometry, lines ate used descriptively to talk about the geodesics in hyperbolic, spherical and elliptic geometry. This is *not* irrelevant, but pertinant to a discussion where you are bring needlessly pedantic.

Comment: @Eletie: I said geodesics are *conceptually* the straight lines in non-Euclidean geometry. Not that they were analogous. When you are talking about "what curve locally minimises the distance on a sphere" then you are talking about spherical geometry in the context of Euclidean geometry, and not spherical geonetry qua spherical grometry, that is as a non-Euclidean geometry. You're confusing geometries here.

Comment: And I said, the word 'line' is completely fine. The fact of the matter is that straight lines don't exist in curved spaces. On more than one occasion you talk about straight lines in non-Euclidean geometry, which is wrong! E.g. "geodesics, that is straight lines, on pseudo-Riemannian manifolds...". My comment is pointing out that this isn't correct. Moreover, I was **not** talking about spherical geometry in the context of Euclidean geometry (which doesn't even mean anything). The definition of a geodesic *is* a locally length-minimising curve. You misquoted me and created your own confusion.

Comment: Maybe my question was poorly formulated as well. I just wanted to know if the intrinsic derivative of the contravariant components of a vector being null implied that the intrinsic derivative of the covariant components of a vector is also null

Comment: @Eletie: The term line is used in [absolute geometry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_geometry) which is the generalisation of Euclidean geometry without the axiom of  parallel lines. As I've already pointed out, the term line there is used and also the term line implies straightness - we don't say straight curve in the same way we don't say a curved line. This is why we have the terms curve and line. Like I've already pointed out you're being pedantic. Geodesics *are* the straight lines in non-Euclidean geometry and are said as such.

Comment: @Jorge Casajus: Your question is fine. It does as the metric converts between covariant and contravariant components and as the metric is non-degenerate it maps null vectors to null vectors.

Comment: @Eletie: Let me take a different tack. In non-Euclidean geometry, it's intrinsic notions that matter, hence straight lines have to be intrinsically defined and this means they are defined as locally distance minimising curves, aka geodesics. This goes for Euclidean geometry as well as non-Euclidean geonetries such as spherical, elliptic and hyperbolic geometry. You're wromg about how you are using these terms because you're envisaging them being embedded in Euclidean space and this is an extrinsic characterisation.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Look at any text on GR or differential geometry. One of the first things they point out is that straight lines (and the notion itself) *does not exist* in non-Euclidean spaces. (They usually say a geodesic is a generalised notion of a straight line). A geodesic is *more general* than a straight line: a straight line *is* a geodesic in flat space. You're redefining terms now, which isn't something anybody does in these contexts. We're talking about curved spacetime (differentiable manifolds), and we should rightly be speaking of geodesic curves.

Comment: @MoziburUllah If you wish to use non-standard terminology (where geodesic is replaced with straight line verbatim) in the context of GR/differential-geometry, that's unhelpful at best and at worst it's just incorrect.

Comment: @Eletie: I'm not using non-standard terminology. As you can see (or rather probably don't) fron the link I provided on non-Euclidean geometry, you will see *lines* are the standard terminology used in non-Euclidean geometry. It's also what characterises straightness in intrisic geonetry and not extrinsic geometry. You're being needlessly pedantic as well as being wrong.

Comment: @Eletie: Do you happen to know the difference between *intrinsic* and *extrinsic* geometry?

Comment: @MoziburUllah My problem is the usage of 'straight lines in curved spaces'. You will not find this in any reputable texts, because it gives the wrong implication. So you *are* using non-standard terminology by equating two distinct concepts of a 'geodesic' and a 'straight line'. Intrinsic and extrinsic geometry have nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Eletie: I'm repeating myself here, but it bears repeating: Do you know the difference between *intrinsic* and *extrinsic* geometry? Do you know what is synthetic non-Euclidean geometry. It appears not because you are making the same mistake. If you look into any reputable book of non-Euclidean geometry you will see the term line to describewhat is known in differential geometry as geodesics. It's called non-Euclidean geometry because the straight lines there are not the straight lines of Euclidean geometry ...

Comment: @Eletie: ... Notably, the *same* definition of straight line is used in both. They are straight lines.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Yes I of course do know the difference, I've published papers in the field of gravity and modified gravity. Whether you like it or not, we *are* dealing with differential geometry and GR here (see the question tags). The link you even posted spoke of lines but *not straight lines* because as soon as you move to non-Euclidean geometry it's *not standard*. If you like Wiki, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_(geometry) where it's clear that in this context geodesics replaces straight-lines as standard terminology.

Comment: @MoziburUllah You also may not be aware but in different fields of mathematics and physics, words and concepts have different meanings and implications. In GR and differential geometry applied to physics, straight line implies a geodesic on *flat space*, not just a general geodesic. As this is a question about GR, it makes sense to use the standard terminology.

Comment: @Eletie: I am aware of that terms ate both ised dicfetently in different ateas of science, or with a didference of emphasis. Historically speaking axiomatic non-Euclidean geometry was invented by mathematicians and the term line is taken from Euclid and it is a straight line. Would there have been such a debate about the reality of non-Euclidean geometry ifvfrom the outset it was understood they were talking about curves. No, of course not. It's *only* when it is *modelled* by a geometry, such as sphereical geometry, that we see that it's straight lines are curved.

Comment: @MoziburUllah I'll stick to terminology where I don't end up with statements like "straight lines are curved", just like is usually done in GR where straight-line implies flat space geodesic.

Comment: Well that escalated quickly

Comment: @Eletie: You're welcome to stick to your terminology, I'll stick to mine.

Comment: @Jorge Casajus: Well it's laid to rest now ;-).